# Iterating clipping process through list of geodataframes

Tags: python, shapefile, clip, geopandas, iteration

I have a folder full of shapefiles, I would like to read them into geopandas and then clip them all to one boundary iteratively. I have loaded all of the shapefiles into a list with this correctly thanks to @Kadir Şahbaz:

```
import glob
import geopandas as gpd
shapefiles = glob.iglob('E:/folder/shapefiles/*.shp')

gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file) for file in shapefiles]
```

However now I am stuck on iterating through each shapefile (geodataframe in the list gdfs). The code below only applies the clip to the first shapefile(item) in the list:

```
for shapefiles in gdfs:
    clipped = [gpd.clip(shapefiles, boundary)
```

I need to iterate the clip through each shapefile(geodataframe) in the list (and later save each as a separate shapefile).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension is very Python.

```
clipped = [gpd.clip(s, boundary) for s in shapefiles]
```

But often it's easier and more flexible to loop, especially if there are clip polygons for each shapefile. Let's say *clip_bounds* contains a list of clip bounds in the same order as the shapefile list:

```
shapefiles = glob.iglob('E:/folder/shapefiles/*.shp')
for file, clipper in list(zip(shapefiles,clip_bounds)):
    gpd.clip(gpd.read_file(file),clipper).to_file(file.replace('.shp','.clipped.shp')
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code you can use to get what you want:

```
for shapefiles in gdfs:
    clipped = gpd.clip(shapefiles, boundary)
    clipped.to_file("your local system path")
```

Here I assume that your all shapefiles and boundary polygon are having same projections. If not then you can change the projection of your boundary polygon (if it's also in a geodataframe by using boundary.to_crs(shapefiles.crs)) in run time and then use the above code which I have written. Or if your boundary polygon is not in geodataframe (it's simply a polygon) then you can use from "shapely.ops import transform" module to change the projection to the projection of your shapefiles.

Comment: Sorry but the code you have written does not iterate (clip) through each geodataframe (shapefiles) in the list (gdfs), instead it only clips the first geodataframe and stores it as a single geodataframe which does not solve my problem. Also I will need to save each geodataframe in the list into a separate shapefile so clipped.to_file("your local system path") will not work for that either